# Ticks does not show origin in plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am unable to denote the origin of my plot.

```
plot1 = Plot[ccads, {\[Sigma], 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 3}, 
Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -1, 1}}, 
Epilog -> {Black, PointSize@Large, Point[{0.07957747154594766`, 0}],
Point[{0.23873241463784303`, 0}]} ,  
AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[4 \[Pi] Subscript[G, 4 ] \[Sigma]], 
HoldForm[Subscript[\[CapitalLambda], 3]]}, PlotLabel -> None, 
LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

[image]

It does not appear automatically and unfortunately nor with my attempt of brute force using

```
Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -1, 1}}
```

Actually, I don't want anything but the "0" denoting the origin. How can I accomplish this?

Unfortunately, it is not an option to place a text "0" at the origin since it will interfere with the axes in a way that looks unprofessional. I am very surprised it is so little or bad information on how to accomplish this simple task. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: There is a conflict in your code. On the one hand, you plot from 0 to 0.5 along the axis sigma. On the other hand, you expect to have ticks {0, 1, 2}. You need to plot until sigma=2.1 or 2.2 to see the tick 2. Further, plotting with the axis does not allow to put the tick in the origin. If you need that try plotting with the frame. That is, include the option `Frame->True` and use `FrameTicks->{....}` instead of `Ticks`. If you would post your function ccads the help could have been more  to the point.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly specify both horizontal plot range and `AxesOrigin`:

```
Plot[5 x^2 - .5, {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1.5, 3}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize@Large, Point[{0.08, 0}], Point[{0.2`, 0}]}]
```

> [image: plot]